# Верстал макет на ReactJS, через время пропали картинки, помогите

Tags: reactjs

делал макет, зашел через неделю, все работает, только картинки не отображает, чего так, не пойму, подскажите.

- в гите на ветке билда, пару штук не работает
- когда запускаю проект, вообще все не работают.

картинки кидал простым форматом:
`<img src="/img/header.png" alt="img"/>`

вот ссылка на гит проект, ето лендинг, если поможет:
https://github.com/dima-kulikov/Landing-Modern-Interior--react

Comment: опубликуйте проект на gitpages, он автоматически публикуется из react-приложения в одну команду. [инструкция](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages). так выкачивать кучу мегабайт, чтобы собрать ваш проект лень. а вобще в react ссылки только абсолютные (из-за роутинга), что может создать проблемы. и сами понимаете, react - это динамический html, он может как угодно меняться в процессе работы приложения. поэтому фраза: кидал просто выглядит забавно.

Comment: gitpages - я же скинул сверху ссылку на страницу готовую гитхаба.

Comment: да, нашел опубликованную версию (хорошей практикой является указание ссылки в Readme.md). думаю дело было так: пока разрабатывали, картинки были. потом решили опубликовать для демонстрации, но при этом поломали девелоперскую версию. подробнее в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

стало интересно и запустил ваш проект в режиме отладки (npm start). и действительно картинки не показываются.

посмотрел исходники, там написан такой код:
`<img src="./img/crafted-1.png" alt="nordic" />`

почитал немного [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react). судя по количеству лайков, проблема у многих.

одно из решений:
`<img src={require("../../img/crafted-1.png")} alt="nordic" />`

в такой реализации и в режиме разработки, и в режиме сборки картинки есть.

предвосхищаю стандартное возражение: ну у меня же работало. да действительно работало, до тех пор пока вы не задали homepage в package.json в виде домен/папка. замените на `"homepage": "https://dima-kulikov.github.io/"` или `"homepage": "/"` и все будет прекрасно работать в режиме отладки (не уверен, что на гитхаб страницах после этого будет работать)